# Post-hoc tests for lmer for two and three-way interactions performing ANOVA type III

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, interaction, post-hoc

In R, I am trying to perform post-hoc tests on a significant three-way interaction involving  two 2-level factors (bodymanipulation, soa) and a continuous variable (prosthesis_partofbody). The model I fitted and the relative code is the following:

```
mlm1 <- lmer(formula = key_press ~  bodymanipulation*soa*prosthesis_partofbody +
           (1|subject_id), data = data)
anova(mlm1)
```

In this way, I obtained a type III ANOVA with Satterthwaite's method table, which showed a significant three way-interaction (but no significant or trends for the two-way interaction.
I produced a plot for this interaction with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( Data[which(group == "AMP"),], aes(x=prosthesis_partofbody, y= key_press, group = interaction(soa, bodymanipulation))) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se = FALSE, alpha = 0.1, aes(lty=bodymanipulation, color=soa))
```

and here is the plot:
[image: Plot three-way interaction]

Which kind of post-hoc test should I perform, and how can I formally report the results in a scientific manuscript?

Comment: What is `soa` ? From the legend, it seems like it might be numeric rather than categorical ? If so then treating it as numeric will make interpretation much easier. Anyway, why do you need a post-hoc test ? Doesn't the output of `summary(mlm1)` answer your research question(s) ?

Comment: SOA is a factor with 4 levels. summary(mlm1) provides the estimates of the comparison of the reference cell to all the others. However, I am interested in exploring the three-way interaction. I would like to show that the higher is prosthesis_partofbody the more body manipulation is affecting the SOA650 and SOA750 but not SOA150, SOA250. This seems to be true when I observe the graph but I am curious to know how I can explore this interaction formally and report the results in a manuscript.  Thank you.